# How can I run a script in another process on Windows Server 2008, using PHP v5.4?

Tags: php

The main reason is because **I don't want to hold up the current PHP process**.  I want users to be able to navigate around during the script execution.

The script in question (`importer.php`) updates a `txt` file with a percentage as it completes, javascript intercepts this `txt` file and outputs the percentage using a timer every 5 seconds to keep the user updated (all in the form of a load bar).

I've been able to launch the script like so:

```
$cmd = '"C:\/path\/to\/v5.4\/php" importer.php';
pclose(popen($cmd, "r"));
exit;
```

This runs the script, but hangs the current process until `importer.php` completes.  Is there a way to get out of the current process and launch this using another one instead?

I read that using `&` at the end of the cmd tells the script to not wait, but I believe this is a `*nix` command and since I'm running on a `Windows` box, I can't use it... unless perhaps there is an alternative for `Windows`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using a **WshShell Object**; `WScript.Shell`

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$WshShell->Run('"C:\/path\/to\/v5.4\/php-win.exe" -f "C:\/path\/to\/code\/snippet\/importer.php" var1 var2 var3', 0, false);
```

**Note:** I have spaces in my file structure so I needed to add quotes around the paths to the files.  I was also able to pass variables, `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`.  I've also used `\/` to escape my slashes.

I'll break the `Run` array down a bit for my case:

1. **The first;** is the `command` you want to run (path to php, path to script, and variables to pass).
2. **The second;** `0` - Hides the window and activates another window (link below for more options).
3. **The third;** `false` - Boolean value indicating whether the script should wait for the program to finish executing before continuing to the next statement in your script. If set to `true`, script execution halts until the program finishes.

For more information on `WScript.Shell` visit [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for details.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at http://php.net/passthru you should be able to execute your command using that, as long as you redirect your output.

```
$cmd = '"C:\/path\/to\/v5.4\/php" importer.php';
// Use passthrough here, and redirect the output to a temp textfile.
passthru($cmd . '>%TEMP%\importerOutput.txt');
exit;
```

Comment: This still gets held up in the current process.. :/